# POSIX ACLs and the 'sticky' bit applied to a directory

Tags: linux, security, unix, posix, acl

[POSIX.1e](http://wt.tuxomania.net/publications/posix.1e/) was going to define ACL ([Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)) mechanisms for POSIX (amongst other security-related issues), but the proposals were never converted to a formal standard.  Nevertheless, ACLs (not necessarily POSIX.1e ACLs) are supported at least optionally in all the main variants of Unix ([Linux](http://www.cs.unc.edu/cgi-bin/howto?howto=linux-posix-acls), [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/fs-acl.html), [MacOS X](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chmod.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/chmod)[(ACL)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/acl.3.html), [HP-UX](http://www.docs.hp.com/en/5992-3387/ch06s03.html), [AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/topic/com.ibm.aix.security/doc/security/security.pdf) (p107ff), [Solaris](http://www.softpanorama.org/Solaris/ACL/index.shtml)).  One detail I've not yet spotted being discussed is how ACLs on files interact with the sticky bit on a directory.

With a normal directory (no ACLs around to confuse the issue), the permissions can be set to, for example, 1777 (found on /tmp, for example).

```
drwxrwxrwt  16 root     sys         4819 May  4 12:09 /tmp
```

The sticky bit is indicated by the 't' in the last position of the permissions.  It means that a user can only delete a file from the directory if the user can write to the file.  This makes sense; if the user can write to the file, the contents of the file can be destroyed.

My question is:

- Suppose the general (non-ACL) permissions of the /tmp directory are as illustrated above.
- Further suppose that a paranoid user, 'trembler', sets the non-ACL permissions on a file `/tmp/secret` to 600 (user 'trembler', group 'worried').
- Suppose that 'trembler' grants 'rw' access on /tmp/secret to another user, 'blase' via an ACL that cites 'blase' specifically.
- **Can 'blase' delete the file `/tmp/secret`**

If the ACL is taken into account, the answer should be 'yes'; if the ACL is ignored, the answer would be 'no'.  Assuming that ACLs are enabled on the relevant file system, is the behaviour uniform across all Unix variants?

Comment: This article is my favorite one on POSIX ACLs:
https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html#sec:dacl

Comment: It has this interesting quote which mentions implementations across (most) different flavors of linux are at least similar, and mostly use Extented Attributes (IE not affecting the permission bits of the inode itself):

"Because other kernel and user space extensions in addition to ACLs benefit from being able to associate pieces of information with files, Linux and most other UNIX-like operating systems implement a more general mechanism called Extended Attributes (EAs). On these systems, ACLs are implemented as EAs."

Comment: But I'm almost certain without even testing that most linux systems would allow 'blase' do delete `/tmp/secret` if his access was set with `setfacl` that was implemented via EAs. If you REALLY didn't want blase to delete you could use `chattr` to make the file immutable, but that would also prohibit writes.

Comment: The example you've provided is absolutely irrelevant: deleting (unlinking) a file from the directory doesn't have anything to do with the access to the file — but to the permissions of directory in question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming that ACLs are enabled on the relevant file system, is the behaviour uniform across all Unix variants?

As ACLs are not implemented uniformly across Unix variants I would expect the behaviour may differ across Unix variants, but it does not have to. Unless all Unices implement the same (standard) way of ACL, there is IMHO no way to guarantee a uniform behaviour across all Unix variants.